# Use my own domain with Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Is it possible to use my own FQDN with Firebase Dynamic Links, instead of the subdomain offered by Google below `page.link`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible to fully customize the domains of your dynamic links through Firebase. If you have a business need for this, please go ahead and [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with the team. Generally enough demand helps get features prioritized :)